# Jenkins [ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, centos

i have a Problem with my Jenkins.

I am trying to do a Maven ob and getting the following Error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-
plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project com.ibm.solver: Compilation failure
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

okey i've checked my $JAVA_HOME on the Build Server that is a CentOS 6.6 Server from which i got this:

```
[root@mopbz171129 bin]# echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/java/default
```

and my maven -version looks like that

```
[root@mopbz171129 bin]# mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.1.1 (0728685237757ffbf44136acec0402957f723d9a; 2013-09-17 17:22:22+0200)
Maven home: /opt/apache-maven-3.1.1
Java version: 1.7.0_76, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_76/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "2.6.32-504.8.1.el6.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

my java directory looks so

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 Apr 7 10:38 default -> /usr/java/latest
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4096 Apr 7 10:38 jdk1.7.0_76
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Apr 7 10:38 latest -> /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_76
```

and last my JDK Configuration in Jenkins self

under the JDK Sektion

Name: 1.7
JAVA_HOME: /usr/java/default

i don't have any idea whats wrong.

Can u help my guys?

Comment: Could you try modifying JAVA_HOME path to '/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_76' and then try?

Comment: Sounds good but if i understand that right my home ist jdk1.7.0_76 
Look at the last codeblock. default->/usr/java/latest and latest -> /usr/java/jdk1.7.0.76

Comment: Have you correctly configured the JDK inside Jenkins which does not look like.

Answer (score 2):

Try add `<fork>true</fork>`into your **pom.xml** , this works for me.

```
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <fork>true</fork>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```